# How to replace code in <head> sections of all HTML documents in a directory using R

Tags: html, r, xml, r-markdown

I'm looking for an efficient way to modify the code between`<head>` `</head>` tags for a large number of .html documents that are all stored in the same folder.

R is mandotory since this is part of an rmarkdown classroom project and I'd like the code to be understood by students.

For my purpose, it would be sufficient to overwrite every document header with *the same* lines which, e.g., adjust CSS or links .js files.

I tried to do this in R using functions like `readLines()` and `writeLines()` in conjunction with regular expressions but that seems overly cumbersome. I'd like to have a more elegant and specific solution that makes use of the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized, that you wanted to replace all child nodes. Here is the code to achieve that. 
The script uses `lapply` to open each file, parse the XML code, remove all child nodes of `head` and adds a `script` element with the argument `src` to it.

**Replace all child nodes**

```
library(XML)

files <- list.files(full.names = T, pattern = "*.html")

lapply(files, function(f) {
  content  <- xmlInternalTreeParse(f, isHTML = T)
  # get head node
  headNode <- getNodeSet(content, path = "//head")
  # remove all child nodes
  do.call(removeChildren, args = list(kids = names(xmlChildren(headNode[[1]])), node = headNode[[1]]))
  # create new nodes
  newNode  <- newXMLNode("script", attrs = list(src = "myScript.js"))
  # add new nodes
  addChildren(headNode[[1]], newNode)
  saveXML(doc = content, file = f)
})
```

**Append a new node**

```
library(XML)

files <- list.files(full.names = T, pattern = "*.html")

lapply(files, function(f) {
  content  <- xmlInternalTreeParse(f, isHTML = T)
  headNode <- getNodeSet(content, path = "//head")
  newNode  <- newXMLNode("script", attrs = list(src = "myScript.js"))

  addChildren(headNode[[1]], newNode)
  saveXML(doc = content, file = f)
})
```